# Changing the value of an object contained within another object and an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a project where I need the values in an array to change depending on if a button is clicked for that specific item. The issue that I'm having is that I need the `value` of for example `'vegetarian'` to change to `true` when `onChangeValue` is triggered, but I can't figure out how to change the `value` of an item in my `subCategories` and get the whole `data` array to stay in the same format. Currently, I'm getting:

```
 [{"category": "Diet", "name": "pescatarian", "subCategories": [[Object], [Object], [Object]], "value": true}, {"category": "Daily Exercise in Hours", "subCategories": [{name:'one', value: false },{name:'two', value: false }, {name:'three', value: false }, {name:'four', value: false }]}]
```

I've tried changing:

```
 return {
          ...items,
          name: item.name,
          value: changedValue,
        }
```

to

```
 return {
          ...items.subCategories,
          name: item.name,
          value: changedValue,
        }
```

, but that just gives me:

```
[{"0": {"name": "pescatarian", "value": false}, "1": {"name": "vegan", "value": false}, "2": {"name": "vegetarian", "value": false}, "name": "pescatarian", "value": true}, {"category": "Daily Exercise in Hours", "subCategories": [{name:'one', value: false },{name:'two', value: false }, {name:'three', value: false }, {name:'four', value: false }]}]
```

I've tried playing around with this a couple of other way, but they gave worse results. Does anyone know how to do this? I would really appreciate any help or advice. Thank you!

Data:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([
     {
        category: 'Diet',
        subCategories: [
          {name:'pescatarian', value: false },
          {name:'vegan', value: false }, 
          {name:'vegetarian', value: false }
        ],
     }, {
        category: 'Daily Exercise in Hours',
        subCategories: [{name:'one', value: false },{name:'two', value: false }, {name:'three', value: false }, {name:'four', value: false }],
      },
  ])
```

onChangeValue()

```
  const onChangeValue = (item, changedValue) => {
    const newData = data.map(items => {
      if (items.subCategories.some(x => x.name === item.name)) {
        return {
          ...items,
          name: item.name,
          value: changedValue,
        }
       }
      return items
    })
    setData(newData);
  }
```

Array that I need:

```
[{"category": "Diet", "subCategories": [{name: "pescatarian",value: false},{name:"vegan", value: false },{name:"vegetarian", value: true }], {"category": "Daily Exercise in Hours", "subCategories": [{name:'one', value: false },{name:'two', value: false }, {name:'three', value: false }, {name:'four', value: false }]}]
```

Comment: The code you currently have in the `onChangeValue()` _is_ returning the array you have in "Array that I need". Isn't that what you want? What is wrong?

Comment: @acdcjunior Sorry, I made a mistake when I was writing the array that I needed. I corrected it above.

Comment: The `subCategories` format in the first object (`Diet`) is an array of objects, and in the second object (`Daily Exercise in Hours`) is an array of strings, is that correct? If so, what happens when `onChangeValue()` is called with like `onChangeValue('one', true)`?

Comment: @acdcjunior Okay, that's a good point. I changed those to ```{name:'one', value: false },{name:'two', value: false }, {name:'three', value: false }, {name:'four', value: false }```, so that it's uniform

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed that array you need to change is just the first `index`, than I think you just need to map the first `index`.

```
const onChangeValue = (item, changedValue) => {
    const newSub = data[0].subCategories.map(subCat => {
      if (subCat.name === item.name) {
        return {
          ...subCat,
          value: changedValue,
        }
       }
      return subCat
    })
    const newData = data
    newData[0].subCategories = newSub
    setData(newData)
  }
```

Comment: This is actually just a portion of the array that I will end up needing, so I'll definitely need to be able to get to other other indexes. I tried this though to see if it would work for my first index, and unfortunately, it's not changing my ```data ``` array.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to change a property that is in an array that is inside another array, you can nest `.map()` calls, like:

```js
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([
     {
        category: 'Diet',
        subCategories: [
          {name:'pescatarian', value: false },
          {name:'vegan', value: false }, 
          {name:'vegetarian', value: false }
        ],
     }, {
        category: 'Daily Exercise in Hours',
        subCategories: [{name:'one', value: false },{name:'two', value: false }, {name:'three', value: false }, {name:'four', value: false }],
      },
  ])
  
  const onChangeValue = (item, changedValue) => {
    const newData = data.map(items => {
      return {
        ...items,
        subCategories: items.subCategories.map(x => (x.name === item.name ? { ...x, value: changedValue } : x)),
      }
    })
    setData(newData);
  }
  React.useEffect(() => onChangeValue({ name: 'pescatarian' }, true), []);
  return (
    <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, ' ')}</pre>
  );
}


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app'));
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```